# What's the difference of the oldRecord and newRecord in the User Event script of NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

There are three types of User Event:

```
beforeLoad() - newRecord
beforeSubmit() - oldRecord, newRecord
afterSubmit() - oldRecord, newRecord
```

Both the beforeSubmit() and afterSubmit() has the **newRecord** and **oldRecord** parameters, while the beforeLoad() has the **newRecord** but no **oldRecord** parameter.

I am confused about the name of newRecord and oldRecord, does the difference is judged by the record is loaded from or submitted to the database? If yes, the **newRecord** for beforeLoad seems to should be renamed to **oldRecord**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `newRecord` for `beforeSubmit` is the new data that *will be* going into the database. The `oldRecord` is the data that is currently there.

The `newRecord` for `afterSubmit` is the new data that is now in the database. The `oldRecord` is the data that *was* there. `afterSubmit` is read-only.

For `beforeLoad`, it's a new record - so it's named `newRecord` for consistency.

Comment: The `newRecord` for **beforeSubmit** is the new data that will be going into the database. The `oldRecord` is the data that is currently there. <--- Does this mean the `oldRecord` is the data in the database then or the data before user changed on the UI?



Whereas the `newRecord` for **afterSubmit** is the new data that is now in the database. The `oldRecord` is the data that was there. afterSubmit is read-only. <--- Dose this mean the `oldRecord` is the data stored in the database before afterSubmit()?

Comment: For `beforeSubmit`: *Does this mean the oldRecord is the data in the database then or the data before user changed on the UI? * It's the data that is the database before it's submitted, before it's changed in the UI. (As it would be shown in View mode before it's been edited.) For `afterSubmit`, you can think of it as the previous version of the record. So yes, it's the data stored in the database before afterSubmit.

Comment: Is it correct? -->  Data is 1 in the database initially, thus `newRecord` is 1 for **beforeLoad**?
Then user update the data to 2, thus `oldRecord` is 1 and `newRecord` is 2 for **beforeSubmit**?
Then user click 'Save' button, thus `oldRecord` is 1 and `newRecord` is 2 for **afterSubmit**?
Why not name the `newRecord` to `oldRecord` for **beforeLoad** since it is loaded from database not a whole new record?

Comment: Yes, `newRecord` is 1 for beforeLoad. Also, your other assumptions are correct, `oldRecord` is 1 and `newRecord` is 2 for both entry points. For **beforeLoad**, I suppose it could be thought of being just `record` because if it truly is a new record, there's no old record to view. Note also that beforeLoad is read-only.